# If div is not empty, remove X from dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `.details-display` is not empty (which is true in the example below), `.details-group` should be removed. What is wrong with the code below?

HTML

```
<div class="details-group">
    <span class="details">Details [+]</span>
    <div class="details-display">The connecting walkway floats above the second story of the Main hall, joining the North and the South wings.</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
if ( $('.details-group').find('.details-display').length ) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8o49bnxL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code snippet, `$(this)` referred to the window object. You could iterate over the `.details-group` elements using the `.each()` method. In doing so, `$(this)` will refer to the current `.details-group` element.

Also, the element `.details-display` doesn't have any children elements. If you want to check to see if it has any text, you could use the `.text()` method.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/10fawLdp/)

```
$('.details-group').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.details-display').text().trim().length) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think what may be confusing to jquery users is that they are used to using `this` inside all of their event handlers. In this case the context is different. Am I right?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Yea, I definitely see a lot of confusing around `this`. In this case, `this` in the global context. In the above example, it is within the `.each()` method which provides context.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with simply removing it?

```js
if ($('.details-group').find('.details-display').length) {

  $(".details-group").remove();

}
```